# Filename as text watermark, ffmpeg/mencoder

Tags: ffmpeg, mencoder, watermark

I have a bunch of photos (from ip cam) witch i pack into video using mencoder, is there a way to tell mencoder to put each filename on produced video?
(file names, has the photo shot time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Imagemagick to preprocess each image, putting the filename on it.